# Sublime Text 3 - The window is not fix with content of file. The height of the scroll view is longer than the actual content

Tags: scroll, editor, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 but I have an issue.

My document window is not fix with content of file. I can scroll over the actual height of my file.

Nearly, the height of document is the actual size + one more windows height. You can see the image for more details.

Do you know how to fix this? Thanks so much.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpMS1.png

Comment: Did you have some long lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set this option to false
`"scroll_past_end": false`
in your Settings - User file

Answer (score 0):

It's just cosmetic and has no effect on the actual file itself. Those line numbers on the left-hand side show where the document really ends.

*edit - It's actually a setting "scroll_past_end". It must not be on by default because I checked it on my sublime text and now see what you're talking about. It's kind of annoying.

Comment: the question is not "why" but "how". It doesn't matter what his reasons are, he just wants his text editor to behave this way

Comment: With me, it's so annoying... I must scroll more but I don't want to do that